# How to open a file in new tab by default in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want a file to be opened in a new tab when I enter or double click it. I know there is <kbd>t</kbd> shortcut but I always open a file in a new tab and enter is more confortable for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try adding

```
let NERDTreeMapOpenInTab='\r'
```

or

```
let NERDTreeMapOpenInTab='<ENTER>'
```

to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: This also causes enter on a directory to open in a new tab.

Comment: how to traverse between file tabs in vim ?

Comment: It doesn't work with gvim x32 with my windows 7 x64.
Any idea?

Comment: There is this NerdTree + tabs plugin:
https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs could be useful.

Comment: While this technically answers the question, it renders directories inaccessible.

Comment: @alice @oarfish try this: `let NERDTreeMapActivateNode='v'` - you can use the `v` key to open/close directory nodes.

Answer (score 99):

**s** will open the file currently under the cursor in a new vertically split window.
Use **t** to open in a new tab.

Comment: Nice. This closes NERDTree window. Is there anyway to keep it open.

Comment: Found that 'T' opens in new tab

Answer (score 12):

As described in section *NERDTreeCustomOpenArgs* of the NerdTree help, you can use this option to control the opening behavior of files and directories. Add the following statement to your `.vimrc`:

```
let NERDTreeCustomOpenArgs={'file':{'where': 't'}}
```

This ensures in this case that only files in a new tab are opened. All other combinations can be found in the help.

Answer (score 10):

You may want to add https://github.com/Nopik/vim-nerdtree-direnter plugin as well - it fixes the directory opening problem, so enter on directory node will just expand/collapse, not open new tab.

Comment: Tried, this, but didn't work: https://github.com/Nopik/vim-nerdtree-direnter/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

I use following map to do tab traverse :

```
nnoremap <C-l> gt
nnoremap <C-h> gT
```

Comment: Also, would this not conflict the default mapping of moving between split panes? Because I have tried doing exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the plugin. It needs to be added to a file such as: `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/mymapping.vim`. The exact location will depend on what plugin manager you use for vim. e.g. for Plugged it is `~/.vim/plugged/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/mymapping.vim`

This code adds a mapping for the enter key to open files in a new tab while just expanding/collapsing directories. For the new tabs it also mirrors the NERDTree so it can be shared between tabs.

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
  \ 'key': '<CR>',
  \ 'scope': "Node",
  \ 'callback': 'OpenInNewTab',
  \ 'quickhelpText': 'open node' })


" FUNCTION: s:openInNewTab(target) {{{1
function! OpenInNewTab(node)
  if a:node.path.isDirectory
    call a:node.activate()
  else
    call a:node.activate({'where': 't'})
    call g:NERDTreeCreator.CreateMirror()
    wincmd l
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Will this be overwritten if I need to update the plugin? I assume it will if I delete then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

For the double-click event specifically, it is (only?) possible by slightly changing the NERDtree source code (posted here):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570970/5144840

Comment: Please, add the relevant information from your link into your answer.

Comment: Changing the source code is a very bad idea, especially since NerdTree offers a lot of options for configuration.