# remap NERDTree Double Click to 'T'

Tags: vim, vi, nerdtree

Using VIM NERDTree Plugin.

Is there any way to remap the Double Click on a File action to open the file silently in a new tab (<kbd>T</kbd>)?

Comment: Shift+t on any file in NERDTree. Oh sorry, just re-read the question. You required mapping and not just silently opening the file. Trying

Comment: You'll probably need to edit [NERDTree's code](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L2869) by yourself.

Answer (score 7):

**1 Introduction**

This works for NERD tree version [4.2.0](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658).

**2 Open directories and files in a new tab**

If you would like to open directories **and** files in a new tab you can simply add the following line to your `~/.vimrc`.

```
let g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTabSilent = '<2-LeftMouse>'
```

**3 Only open files in a new tab**

If you **only** want to open **files** in a new tab you have to do something more sophisticated.

Add this function somewhere in `NERD_tree.vim`:

```
" opens a file in a new tab
" KeepWindowOpen - dont close the window even if NERDTreeQuitOnOpen is set
" stayCurrentTab: if 1 then vim will stay in the current tab, if 0 then vim
" will go to the tab where the new file is opened
function! s:openInTabAndCurrent(keepWindowOpen, stayCurrentTab)
    if getline(".") ==# s:tree_up_dir_line
        return s:upDir(0)
    endif

    let currentNode = s:TreeFileNode.GetSelected()
    if currentNode != {}
        let startToCur = strpart(getline(line(".")), 0, col("."))

        if currentNode.path.isDirectory
            call currentNode.activate(a:keepWindowOpen)
            return
        else
            call s:openInNewTab(a:stayCurrentTab)
            return
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

and replace the line

```
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <2-leftmouse> :call <SID>activateNode(0)<cr>
```

with:

```
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <2-leftmouse> :call <SID>openInTabAndCurrent(0,1)<cr>
```

You can find this line in the function `s:bindMappings()` in the file `NERD_tree.vim`.

Answer (score 2):

Although my NERDtree version is also reported as 4.2.0 (git cloned 2015-07-22), there seems to have been some major refactoring in the mean time, hence the solution by jens-na in section (3) did not transfer (but there still doesn't seem to be an out-of-the-box solution, either). I had to replace a line in autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim, as per the diff below.
(Note: tested on MacVim)

```
--- .vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim.backup    2015-07-22 19:39:53.000000000 +0200
+++ .vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim  2015-07-22 19:40:44.000000000 +0200
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
     call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<MiddleRelease>', 'scope': "all", 'callback': s."handleMiddleMouse" })
     call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<LeftRelease>', 'scope': "all", 'callback': s."handleLeftClick" })
     call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<2-LeftMouse>', 'scope': "DirNode", 'callback': s."activateDirNode" })
-    call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<2-LeftMouse>', 'scope': "FileNode", 'callback': s."activateFileNode" })
+    call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<2-LeftMouse>', 'scope': "FileNode", 'callback': s."openInNewTab" })
     call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<2-LeftMouse>', 'scope': "Bookmark", 'callback': s."activateBookmark" })
     call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': '<2-LeftMouse>', 'scope': "all", 'callback': s."activateAll" })
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way of doing it for the current NERDTree, also does not have problems with double click on dirs (using Linux with GVim).