# Using multiple files simultaneously with tabs in vim NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Okay, this has been asked [before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680752/how-to-open-a-file-in-new-tab-by-default-in-nerdtree)

But the answers did not really cover what I was looking for. I do not even get the purpose of `t` shortcut, it just opens another nerdtree where I can't even open folders with `enter`.

What I would like to do is to open files in new tabs inside one nerdtree session, just like in any other non-terminal text editor.

Now, if I open another file with enter, it closes the previously edited file. It becomes quite tedious very fast while working on a project.

Anybody has a solution for this?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are using vim tabs wrong, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers

Comment: It seems I am. Interesting. Thanks the link, going to read it now.